# Batch script to find and replace 2 different strings at once

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, replace

I have a XML file like this sample:

```
  <fruit>
      <desc>xxx / yyy / zzz</desc>
  </fruit>
  <fruit>
      <desc></desc>
  </fruit>
  <fruit>
      <desc>abc / def / ghi</desc>
  </fruit>
```

I'm using a batch script to fix the node "desc".
This is the result after fixing:

```
  <fruit>    
      <desc>xxx/yyy/zzz</desc>    
  </fruit>    
  <fruit>    
      <desc>N/A</desc>    
  </fruit>    
  <fruit>    
      <desc>abc/def/ghi</desc>    
  </fruit>
```

How can I replace 2 different strings without scan all the file twice?
This is the script:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "input_xml=xmlfile.xml"

set "search=^<desc^>^</desc^>"
set "search2= / "
set "replace=^<desc^>N/A^</desc^>"
set "replace2=/"
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "!input_xml!" ^& break ^> "!input_xml!" ') do (
  set FixNullNode=%%i
  echo !FixNullNode:%search%=%replace%! >>"!input_xml!" 
)
for /f "delims=" %%v in ('type "!input_xml!" ^& break ^> "!input_xml!" ') do (
  set FixSpaceSlash=%%v
  echo !FixSpaceSlash:%search2%=%replace2%! >>"!input_xml!" 
)
pause
```

Thanks

Comment: I'd not use a batch script to manipulate XML datat as it does not know its structure, rather it just treats it as plain text; if the XML data format is just slightly different (e. g., a line-break is at another position), the batch approach might fail. Better use a language that natively supports XML, like PowerShell, JavaScript, VBScript, etc.

Comment: I'm still learning, for now I can deal with Batch, and it's working well mainly because the XML is well formated and I have some control about it. But Powershell would be the next closer option... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move the second replace into the first for command.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "input_xml=xmlfile.xml"

set "search=^<desc^>^</desc^>"
set "search2= / "
set "replace=^<desc^>N/A^</desc^>"
set "replace2=/"
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "!input_xml!" ^& break ^> "!input_xml!" ') do (
  set "Fix=%%i"
  set "Fix=!Fix:%search%=%replace%!"
  echo !Fix:%search2%=%replace2%! >>"!input_xml!" 
)
```

Comment: Seems to be so simple!
I was trying to create another variable and bring the first variable inside. Of course it was not working... Thank you!

Comment: Hey @Squashman, I was trying to use a second variable, why wasn't working?
set "Fix=%%i" set "Fix2=!Fix:%search%=%replace%!" echo !Fix2:%search2%=%replace2%!